# How to solve grub bootloader problem?

Tags: boot, partitioning, grub2, bootloader

Recently i switched from windows to Ubuntu, i tried to follow a tutorial to install Ubuntu and there were some difference between the disk partitions in the tutorial and my disk and i ignored the differences. Now when booting the bootloader  shows the Windows boot manager as an option [grub bootloader](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c0py5.png), the reason may be because i didn't format the windows boot manager partition.
Is it safe to format this partition and will it disappear from bootloader menu ?
How to make my Ubuntu boot directly without bootloader to show up ?

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the grub customizer app, from ubuntu software. There you can set how many seconds to see the bootloader menu, and possibly turn it off. Tip, you better leave that menu you might need. As for the windows boot option we don't know if you have BIOS or UEFI?

Comment: I have UEFI in my device